# How to place image inside canvas in tkinter

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter, canvas

```
def choose_image():
        global image_object
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select file", filetypes=(("PNG files", "*.png"), ("JPEG files", "*.jpg"), ("JPG files", "*.jpg")))
        # Load the image
        if filename:
            image = Image.open(filename)
            image_width, image_height = image.size
            canvas_width, canvas_height = canvas_image.winfo_width(), canvas_image.winfo_height()
            # Calculate the scaling factor
            scale = min(canvas_width/image_width, canvas_height/image_height)
            new_width = int(image_width*scale)
            new_height = int(image_height*scale)
            # Resize the image
            resized_image = image.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            image_object = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
            # Add the image to the canvas
            canvas_image.delete("all")  # Remove any previously added image
            canvas_image.create_image(canvas_width/2, canvas_height/2, image=image_object)
            print(1)
            canvas_image.image = image_object
            print(2)

    # Create a label for displaying the image
    canvas_image = Canvas(insert, width=150, height=150)
    canvas_image.place(x=500,y=120)

    img_label = Label(insert, text="Upload Photo: ", bg="white", font=("Varenda", 10))
    img_label.place(x=400, y=120)
```

i tried to upload image from device but

```
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist

_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage4" doesn't exist
```

these error are coming

Comment: Such error most probably caused by multiple instances of `Tk`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I built my own window for this I didn't get the error `_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist`. The comment from @acw1668 is most likely correct. I built my window like this:

```
window = Tk()
window.geometry("800x600")

# Create widgets
canvas_image = Canvas(window, width=150, height=150)
canvas_image.place(x=500,y=120)
img_label = Label(window, text="Upload Photo: ", bg="white", font=("Varenda", 10))
img_label.place(x=400, y=120)
button = Button(window, text="Choose Image", command=choose_image)
button.place(x=400, y=200)

# Mainloop
window.mainloop()
```

Including your entire code the following works with only a depreciation warning (I added in the correct imports):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


def choose_image():
    global image_object
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select file", filetypes=(("PNG files", "*.png"), ("JPEG files", "*.jpg"), ("JPG files", "*.jpg")))
    # Load the image
    if filename:
        image = Image.open(filename)
        image_width, image_height = image.size
        canvas_width, canvas_height = canvas_image.winfo_width(), canvas_image.winfo_height()
        # Calculate the scaling factor
        scale = min(canvas_width/image_width, canvas_height/image_height)
        new_width = int(image_width*scale)
        new_height = int(image_height*scale)
        # Resize the image
        resized_image = image.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        image_object = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
        # Add the image to the canvas
        canvas_image.delete("all")  # Remove any previously added image
        canvas_image.create_image(canvas_width/2, canvas_height/2, image=image_object)
        print(1)
        canvas_image.image = image_object
        print(2)

window = Tk()
window.geometry("800x600")

# Create widgets
canvas_image = Canvas(window, width=150, height=150)
canvas_image.place(x=500,y=120)
img_label = Label(window, text="Upload Photo: ", bg="white", font=("Varenda", 10))
img_label.place(x=400, y=120)
button = Button(window, text="Choose Image", command=choose_image)
button.place(x=400, y=200)

# Mainloop
window.mainloop()
```